# How does one load data into Redux asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

Suppose that one has the following component file `HelloForm.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {graphql} from 'react-apollo';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {actions, Control, Form} from 'react-redux-form';
import {compose, withProps} from 'recompose';

import query from './HelloForm.gql';

const passThrough = fn => BaseComponent => props => {
    fn(props, BaseComponent);

    return BaseComponent(props);
};

export const HelloForm = ({onSubmitEventHandler}) =>
    <Form
            className="my-form"
            model="forms.hello"
            onSubmit={onSubmitEventHandler}
    >
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
        <Control.text
            {...props}
            model=".name"
            id="name"
        />

        <button type="submit">Say Hello</button>
    </Form>;

export const enhance = compose(
    connect(),
    withProps({
        onSubmitEventHandler: ({name}) => {
            window.alert(`Hello, ${name}`);
        },
    }),
    graphql(query),
    passThrough(({data, dispatch, loading}) => {
        if (!loading) {
            dispatch(actions.load('forms.hello', data));
        }
    }),
);

export default enhance(HelloForm);
```

This appears to work as expected but one gets the following warning:

> Warning: `setState(...)`: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

However, [React's component documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) suggests that one should dispatch the action during the `componentDidMount` lifecycle event (which can be done with functional components via [`recompose.lifecycle`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle)). But no props are provided to the `componentDidMount` event handler.

What is the proper way to "asynchronously" dispatch actions to Redux?

Comment: Check for redux-saga. I think it may help you.

Comment: @lilezek, if I understand correctly, with [Redux-Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), one would still need to dispatch an action to Redux in a similar manner though.

Comment: Yes, of course. You will not avoid to dispatching actions if you use Redux. Saga helps you to make Redux "not so pure".

Answer (score 0):

The solution was indeed to use the [`recompose.lifecycle`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle) higher-order component. However, one must not use an arrow function. The updated `enchance` higher-order component should be implemented as follows:

```
export const enhance = compose(
    connect(),
    withProps({
        onSubmitEventHandler: ({name}) => {
            window.alert(`Hello, ${name}`);
        },
    }),
    graphql(query),
    lifecycle({
        componentDidMount: function () {
            const {dispatch, loading, recipe} = this.props;

            if (loading) {
                dispatch(actions.load('forms.hello', data));
            }
        },
    }),
);
```